# Feature request: Making the API show profile thumbnails when there are no track thumbnails

Tags: soundcloud

**THIS IS A FEATURE REQUEST FOR THE SOUNDCLOUD CREW** (since they do not respond via api@soundcloud.com)

Like SoundCloud itself, could the API show profile thumbnails when there are no track thumbnails available?

This way, when embedding SoundCloud tracks via Embedly or the like -- ie. http://jsbin.com/kezonutoroma/1/edit -- people won't have to be faced with those empty placeholder images.

https://soundcloud.com/oembed?url=https://soundcloud.com/liv-lykke/andres-haender&format=xml

```
<thumbnail-url>http://a1.sndcdn.com/images/fb_placeholder.png</thumbnail-url>
```

[image]

Should be:

```
<thumbnail-url>http://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000036988237-o1ck0r-t500x500.jpg</thumbnail-url>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a static, more hacky solution:

```
var defaultimg = 'http://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000036988237-o1ck0r-t500x500.jpg';

$('div a').embedly({
  key: '7c6cf67ad409446cacd53309d96b66a0',
  query: {
    maxwidth: 500,
    autoplay: true
  },
  display: function(data, elem){
    $(elem).html('<img src="'+defaultimg+'"/>');

    $(elem).addClass('play')
      .append('<span />')
      .width(data.thumbnail_width)
      .height(data.thumbnail_height)
      .find('span')
      .css('height', data.thumbnail_height)
      .css('width', data.thumbnail_width);
  }
}).on('click', function(){
  var data = $(this).data('embedly');
  $(this).replaceWith(data.html);
  return false;
});
```

http://jsbin.com/qovirepoyoto/1/edit

I would recommend to get the default image via an API call to the user endpoint.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Can you think of a way to make this dynamic? That SoundCloud track is just one of many.

Comment: Just use the normal user endpoint, for that you need to create an app at developer.soundcloud.com - to get at least the client-id. If you have the client-id you can make api-calls.

Comment: Say I got a client ID, where do I take it from there? I found https://github.com/soundcloud/SoundCloud-API-jQuery-plugin but I have no idea how to integrate it with Embedly.

Comment: Sorry, i dont know anything about these plugins. One way to retrieve the users profile picture could be that: http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/mau9s80w/

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot! But like you say, it's all a bit hacky. Would prefer for this to just be default behavior in the API itself.

Comment: Yes and no. Someone could confuse it may be. Besides that I would not use the oembed stuff or outdated libaries like the mentioned above. I'd use the JS-SDK and build my own logic on top.

Comment: Confuse how? And to clarify, you're calling SoundCloud-API-jQuery-plugin outdated, not jquery-embedly right?

Comment: SoundCloud-API-jQuery-plugin was updated 4 years ago. Regarding the default API behaviour, i am the wrong contact person - i dont work for soundcloud.

Comment: Wow. Didn't notice it was that old. Anyway, hope someone from the API crew sees this. Thanks a lot though man!

Comment: By answering this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066587/track-imagesartwork-url-not-returned-by-soundcloud-api/26074378#26074378 - this feature is more less built in. When you call for a track, you will always find the default avatar_picture in the user object. But i dont know how to implement it with oembed directly.