# Track Images(artwork_url) not returned by Soundcloud API

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, soundcloud

I am using Soundcloud API to retrieve a list a tracks in my windows phone app(using C#). In the .json file of the tracks, I see that there is no image returned for some tracks (i.e. **"artwork_url":null**).
[image](NOTE: On the other hand, in other 3rd party Soundcloud apps on WP8, I can see the same tracks along with their respective images.)

Is there any way I could receive complete information? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its null, its not defined. 
SC uses on their website a logic to use the default avatar when there is no artwork defined.

Compare with this sketch:

```
SC.get('/tracks/97617992', function(sound) {
console.log(sound.artwork_url);
$('#result').append('<img src="' +sound.user.avatar_url+'"/>' );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/ngtzdx8c/

Comment: This is not the case. The picture shown along the track uses "artwork_url". Just try the track with id: 159966669. The artwork_url(actual image for the track on SoundCloud) and the user.avatar_url give different images. http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/ngtzdx8c/ http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/ngtzdx8c/ https://soundcloud.com/pitbull/fireball

Comment: sure, they are different - one is the avatar (user), one is for the track. the picture above shows track-id: 97617992. your mentioned id will have an artwork as well as avatar_url. check that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/0ry1qvtp/

Comment: Since I'm binding my Image control with the artwork_url property, no rendering takes place when "artwork_url=null" (and as you know, artwork_url and user.avatar_url are different). So how do I receive and thereby render complete information?

Comment: This is another question, its your program logic. If you wont change to much code, i would may be add an if-statement while parsing the json if artwork_url = null, artwork_url = user.avatar_url.